# The program doesn't follow the steps on the 2nd, 3rd,... searches Trying to debug (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm trying to debug a small program that I have on codepen and I'm having a problem with the sequence of the program. If you show the console you will see the steps that the program is following.

After the second, third... search the program doesn't follow the steps as it should do it. I would appreciate some help.

Please, run the code on codepen because it doesn't run the same way on stackoverflow's snippets.

http://codepen.io/rafahuelin/pen/JEdqOa?editors=0011

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

//1 Appears the magnifier icon 
 console.log("1");
 $("#created").addClass("created-start");
 $("#search").html("<div id='magnifier' class='search-init animated fadeIn'> <div id='magnifier-stick' class='stick-appears'></div> </div>");
 
//2 When clicking on the icon appears the input form
 console.log("2");
 $("#magnifier").on("click", function() {
   $("#magnifier-stick").addClass("animated fadeOut stick-disappears").removeClass("stick-appears");
   $(".search-init").addClass("search-input").removeClass("search-init");
   setTimeout(function() {  //waits for 1s
    readyToSearch();
   }, 1000);
 });

//3/9  input area prepared to search 
function readyToSearch() {
 console.log("3/9");
 $("#search").html("<div class='search-input'><form><input id='input-form' class='animated fadeIn' type='text' name='searchContent' placeholder='Type Your Search Here...'></form></div>");
 $("#input-form").prop('disabled', false); //trying to debug *******************************
 $("#input-form").focus();

 
//4 After pressing Enter, 

$("#search").on("submit", function(e) {
 console.log("4");
 var searchText = $("#input-form").val(); //<---JQuery ///  var searchText = document.getElementById("input-form").value; <---In javascript
 $("#input-form").prop('disabled', true); //Disable textbox to prevent multiple submit // trying to debug *****************************************
 moveSearchUp(searchText);
 sendToAPI(searchText);
 return false;
});

} // input area prepared to search

//6 send request to API
function sendToAPI(searchText) { 
 console.log("6");
 var searchRequest = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=" + searchText + "&namespace=&limit=10&callback=?";
 var tmp = $.ajax({
    url: searchRequest,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
     showList( data );
     console.log("6 searchRequest: " + searchRequest);
     console.log("6 searchText: " + searchText);
     console.log("6 data[1]: " + data[1] );
        },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
     console.log(errorMessage);
    }
    });
} 

//7 show the results 
function showList (data) {
 console.log("7");
 $("#results").addClass("results").html("<ul>"); 
 for (i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
  $("#results").append("<div class='result-item'><a href='" + data[3][i] + "' target='blank_'><li> <h2 class='title'>" + data[1][i] + "</h2><p class='description'>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li></a></div>");
  if(i != data[1].length - 1){
   $("#results").append("<hr>")
  }
 }
 $("#results").append("</ul>");
 
 //8 click on the close X
 $("#close").on("click", function() {
  console.log("8");
  $("#results").remove();
  $("#created").addClass("created-start");
  readyToSearch();
 });
 
}
 
//5 search-input moves up 
function moveSearchUp(searchText) {
 console.log("5");
 $("#created").removeClass("created-start");
 $(".search-input").removeClass("search-input").addClass("search-top");
 setTimeout(function() {  //waits for 1s
  $("#input-form").css({'width': searchText.length * 12 + 'px'});
 }, 500);
 if ($("#close > i").hasClass("fa-times") === false) { 
  $("form").append("<div id='close'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>"); 
 }
 if ($("#created").hasClass("created-start") === false) {
  $("#created").addClass("created-start");
 }
} // end function moveSearchUp
 


}); // $(document).ready
```

```css
.search-init {
 height: 70px;
 width: 70px;
 border: 4px solid rgba(185, 18, 27, 1);
 border-radius: 35px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
 -ms-animation-duration: 3s;
 -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
}

#magnifier-stick.stick-appears {
 height: 20px;
 width: 0;
 border: 2px solid rgba(185, 18, 27, 1);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 top: 54px;
 left: 54px;
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#magnifier-stick.stick-disappears {
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 border: 2px solid rgba(185, 18, 27, 1);
 transform: rotate(-95deg);
 top: 54px;
 left: 54px;
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 200ms ease;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
 -ms-animation-duration: 0.2s;
 -moz-animation-duration: 0.2s;
}

#input-form, #input-form:focus {
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 120px;
 border-radius: 35px;
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 transition: all 500ms 500ms ease;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.search-input{
 line-height: 56px;
 height: 70px;
 width: 570px;
 border: 4px solid rgba(185, 18, 27, 1);
 border-radius: 35px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 500ms 500ms ease;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

/* Change the background color of the input */
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #F6E497 inset;
}

.search-top {
 line-height: 40px;
 height: 54px;
 border: 4px solid rgba(185, 18, 27, 1);
 border-radius: 27px;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 500ms 500ms ease;
}

input:-webkit-autofill{
 background: none;
}

.results {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 90px;
 padding: 30px;
 list-style: none;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.results a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.result-item {
 border-left: solid 7px rgba(185, 18, 27, 0);
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
}

.result-item:hover {
 border-left: solid 7px rgba(185, 18, 27, 1);
 transition: all ease 0.8s;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}

.title {
 font-size: 2.5rem;
 font-weight: 500;
 margin-top: 0;
 color: #4C1B1B;
}

.description {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 color: #BD8D46;
}

hr {
 border: 0;
  height: 2px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(185, 18, 27, 0), rgba(185, 18, 27, 0.45), rgba(185, 18, 27, 0));
}

.created {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 40px;
 font-size: 2.4rem;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #B9121B;
}

.created-start {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 45px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translatex(-60%);
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.created a {
 color: #B9121B;
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.name {
 font-size: 2rem;
}

.created a:hover, .created a:visited {
 color: #B9121B;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* .delete-search::after {
 content: "<div id='close'><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>";
} */

#close {
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 background: none;
 color: #B9121B;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="search">
  </div>
 <div id="results">
 </div>
 <footer>
  <div id="created" class="created">
   <span class="by">&mdash; </span> <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/rafahuelin/"><span class="name">Rafa Huelin</span> <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <span class="by"> &mdash;</span>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please detail the steps the script should follow in your question. People like working to find the answer, not the question.

Comment: @daveyfaherty on the Javascript code you can see the numbers on the comments and when you run the program the numbers are appearing on the console so it's easier to debug the code. The user follows the next steps: 1-click on the magnifier, 2- input a search and press enter, 3- once you have your results you can press the X to cancel the current search and place a new one, 4- repeat for as long as you want. It's not working 100% but the main problem right know is to find out why the program is not following the desired steps??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that each time you call the *readyToSearch* function, you are binding the submit event.
As you call *readyToSearch* each time you click the close button, the submit is being bind again.

If you move the submit the  event binding out of the *readyToSearch* function it works as supposed.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

//1 Appears the magnifier icon 
 console.log("1");
 $("#created").addClass("created-start");
 $("#search").html("<div id='magnifier' class='search-init animated fadeIn'> <div id='magnifier-stick' class='stick-appears'></div> </div>");

//4 After pressing Enter, 
 $("#search").on("submit", function(e) {
  console.log("4");
  var searchText = $("#input-form").val(); //<---JQuery ///  var searchText = document.getElementById("input-form").value; <---In javascript
  $("#input-form").prop('disabled', true); //Disable textbox to prevent multiple submit // trying to debug *****************************************
  moveSearchUp(searchText);
  sendToAPI(searchText);
  return false;
 });
 
//2 When clicking on the icon appears the input form
 console.log("2");
 $("#magnifier").on("click", function() {
   $("#magnifier-stick").addClass("animated fadeOut stick-disappears").removeClass("stick-appears");
   $(".search-init").addClass("search-input").removeClass("search-init");
   setTimeout(function() {  //waits for 1s
    readyToSearch();
   }, 1000);
 });

//3/9  input area prepared to search 
function readyToSearch() {
 console.log("3/9");
 $("#search").html("<div class='search-input'><form><input id='input-form' class='animated fadeIn' type='text' name='searchContent' placeholder='Type Your Search Here...'></form></div>");
 $("#input-form").prop('disabled', false); //trying to debug *******************************
 $("#input-form").focus();

} // input area prepared to search

//6 send request to API
function sendToAPI(searchText) { 
 console.log("6");
 var searchRequest = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=" + searchText + "&namespace=&limit=10&callback=?";
 var tmp = $.ajax({
    url: searchRequest,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
     showList( data );
     console.log("6 searchRequest: " + searchRequest);
     console.log("6 searchText: " + searchText);
     console.log("6 data[1]: " + data[1] );
        },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
     console.log(errorMessage);
    }
    });
} 

//7 show the results 
function showList (data) {
 console.log("7");
 $("#results").addClass("results").html("<ul>"); 
 for (i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
  $("#results").append("<div class='result-item'><a href='" + data[3][i] + "' target='blank_'><li> <h2 class='title'>" + data[1][i] + "</h2><p class='description'>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li></a></div>");
  if(i != data[1].length - 1){
   $("#results").append("<hr>")
  }
 }
 $("#results").append("</ul>");
 
 //8 click on the close X
 $("#close").on("click", function() {
  console.log("8");
  $("#results").remove();
  $("#created").addClass("created-start");
  readyToSearch();
 });
 
}
 
//5 search-input moves up 
function moveSearchUp(searchText) {
 console.log("5");
 $("#created").removeClass("created-start");
 $(".search-input").removeClass("search-input").addClass("search-top");
 setTimeout(function() {  //waits for 1s
  $("#input-form").css({'width': searchText.length * 12 + 'px'});
 }, 500);
 if ($("#close > i").hasClass("fa-times") === false) { 
  $("form").append("<div id='close'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>"); 
 }
 if ($("#created").hasClass("created-start") === false) {
  $("#created").addClass("created-start");
 }
} // end function moveSearchUp
 


}); // $(document).ready
```

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly. I appreciate that you took the time to spot it :)

Comment: I'm glad to help :) also, I sometimes I like to do some javascript analysis/debugging. Eheh